# php get file content with explode

Tags: php, file, preg-match, explode

I would like to get the file content of an usual txt file to an array by explode. Unfortunately if I use the usual file open it opens the file, but seperates it by lines. That is not useful as my format is always like this:

Date|name|specialtext|description|

but it can also happen that description has several lines, that s why the usual method is not working.

I tried it with that here:

```
$lines = file($filename1);
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        if (preg_match('/^\s*|+\R*$/', $line)) { echo "finally"; }
```

| should be the sperator. But that also does not work.

Comment: why not just use `fgetcsv()`? It can use custom separators. and file is doing what it's designed for it. it has no idea you're using a multi-line format. It's up to YOU, in that case, to write a file reader to handle it.

Comment: don't paste blocks of code into a comment. it's unreadable. edit your question.

Comment: I used fgetcsv() like this here: 

  $filename1  = htmlspecialchars($_GET['filename'], ENT_QUOTES);
  
  if (($handle = fopen($filename1, "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
   $num = count($data);
   echo "<p> $num in row $row: <br /></p>\n";
   $row++;
   for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
   }
  }
  fclose($handle);
  }  

But unfortunately that also didn't work. Doesn't it have to be a txt file for using fgetcsv? It is a .txt file.